# fast enumeration on a NSArray / NSMutableArray returned from block

Tags: objective-c

I have the following in a success block for an AFNetworking getPath call:

```
+(void)allItemsWithBlock: (void (^)(NSArray *items)) block
{
   ...
   NSMutableArray *mutableItems = [NSMutableArray array];
   for (NSDictionary *attributes in [responseObject valueForKey:@"data"]) {
      Item *item = [[Item alloc] initWithAttributes:attributes];
      [mutableItems addObject:item];
   } 
   NSLog(@"here is a count: %i", [mutableItems count]);
   if(block){
      block(mutableItems);
   }
```

and in the block that gets passed in, I have the following but get the error listed as a comment:

```
[Item allItemsWithBlock:^(NSArray *items){
    for(Item *thisItem in *items){  // The type 'NSArray' is not a pointer to a fast-enumerable object
      NSLog(@"in the block here");
    }
}];
```

I've read up on trying to fast-enumeration but am not sure what the problem is. Is the NSMutableArray -> NSArray an issue? Is it because this array is created in a block and thus could be seen as possibly still 'open for change'?  I have seen code like this before in our projects and doesn't seem to be a problem.

thx for any help

Comment: Don't prefix methods w/`get`, please.   That is reserved for a very special purpose.

Comment: To be more specific, `get` is typically used when the caller must provide their own buffer. For example, `NSString` has a method `getCharacters:range:` where the caller must provide a buffer. Similarly, `NSArray` has a method called `getObjects:range:`. Another example, `NSStream` has a class method `getStreamsToHost:port:inputStream:outputStream:` where the method returns two streams via "output" parameters.

Comment: thx @bburn just testing out a few things, updated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because NSArray *items is already a pointer to an array, *items is trying to find a pointer to a pointer, which it is not.

Just replace:

```
for(Item *thisItem in *items){
```

with:

```
for(Item *thisItem in items){
```